# "if it weren't for you" meaning in context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> **Lucy**: My parents don't let me go to the movies on my own, and they
> don't want to go with me either. What should I do?
>
> **Austin**: Have you asked your older brother to go with you?
>
> **Lucy**: Hm, thanks... okay. I'll ask Steven.
>
> *Next Day*
>
> **Steven**: Mr. Austin, thanks for your advice! I wouldn't have got to
> watch that cartoon if it weren't for you. It was awesome!

In above dialogues, I'm confused with what Steven says to Austin.

> if it weren't for you

What is Steven trying to say here?

Comment: It means "if there wasn't your(Austin's) advice, we(Steven and Lucy) couldn't have had watched the movie", That's Steven thanking Austin giving Lucy the advice.

Answer (score 1):

After a little research, I found that,

**"If it weren't for"** is an idiom which can be used in place of **"Without"**. [More Info](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if%20it%20were%20not%20for)

So, Steven's dialogue can be taken as

> I wouldn't have got to watch that cartoon ***without*** you

Answer (score 0):

> **if it were not for​/​if it had not been for** ([Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/if-it-were-not-for-if-it-had-not-been-for))
> used for saying who or what prevented something from happening
> *If it hadn’t been for the two men who rescued me, I’d probably have drowned.*
> *If it weren’t for the fact that he’s my father, I’d accuse him in public.*

OP seems to have got the character names a bit mixed up, but it seems to me that ***Lucy*** is saying this to her older brother ***Steven***, who graciously took her to the cinema. Effectively, she's ***thanking*** him.

Their parents didn't want to go with Lucy, but they wouldn't let her go to the cinema alone either, so she could only go and watch the movie because of what Steven did.

---

EDIT: - OP's cited text has radically changed since I wrote the above. It now appears that it's actually Steven who's thanking Mr Austin - for having advised his younger sister Lucy to ask him (Steven) to take her to the cinema.

He's grateful because Mr Austin's suggestion led to him (Steven) seeing a cartoon that he really enjoyed, which he ***wouldn't otherwise have seen*** *(**were it not for / had it not been for** what Mr Austin did).*

Comment: It's entirely possible that Steven could be saying it to Austin - thanking him for giving Lucy the idea.

Comment: No, there are three characters here.Austin is like a neighbor of them(Steven and Lucy) and chatting over social media platform.

Comment: It's not Lucy thanking. It's Steven (thanking Austin for giving her sister his advice(to go to movie together)),.

Comment: @rjpond It's not "entirely possible", but rather perfectly clear to me given the OP's sentence. That very Steven is thanking.

Comment: The names of the speaker / addressee aren't really relevant to the question as asked (what does ***if it weren't for X*** mean?). All that matters is person Y wouldn't have been able to do or have something were it not for the fact that person X did something (specifically, X took Y to the cinema).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica No, it is perfectly relevant. Actually, the OP found out the idiom and that fits accurately. You are just making your opinion.

Comment: @Kentaro: I don't really even *have* an opinion as to who was speaking to who, because it doesn't make any difference to what's being asked ***as an ELL question***. What matters here is the definition of the English idiom ***if it weren't for X*** - exactly how to apply that dictionary definition to any given context is up to the reader of the text wherein it occurs.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica But then you couldn't answer. The OP found the idiom right below.

Comment: @Kentaro: <sigh> I no longer understand why OP asked this question in the first place. I cited Macmillan's definition, but apparently he needed to go and find a different one from Merriam-Webster in order to understand the idiom.